# literal with two actions(Custemize a literal) in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i need a literal for doing an action. the asp literal is only for warning. but i need the exact literal in this page!

if you want to delete your comment here a literal come up and ask you if you want to delete it or not. and it has tow buttons (yes and no)
how can i have such a literal like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the jQuery UI Modal Dialog

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation